Escape velocity of a Black Hole
Maybe a trivial question caused by my poor understanding of escape velocity definition. If the escape velocity is the minimum speed that a body has to have to escape from the gravity of another body without propulsion, and if the escape velocity of a Black Hole within the Schwarzschild radius is equal to the speed of light; in theory, if a spaceship would cross that border it would be able to return back, assuming it could provide continuous thrust to counterbalance the gravitational pull. This is true even if its speed is lower than the escape velocity. Is it a correct or am I missing something?

Does this answer your question? Can you exit the event horizon with a rocket?

FWIW: The idea of a "dark star" with escape velocity greater than the speed of light was proposed in 1784, and it's true that as you approach a black hole, the escape velocity from where you are approaches the speed of light, but that is not how its event horizon is defined. TLDR: The event horizon of a black hole is the surface, within which, spacetime is so curved that all timelike world lines lead to the singularity. [Sorry, I can't find a TLDR-level article that explains it. Textbooks and Google are your friends.]
